# How to use Activator.CreateInstance to reflect a type whose constructor parameter differs only by ref

Tags: c#, reflection

How to use reflection to create an instance of the type below while calling a specific constructor? Checked all the overloads of Activator.CreateInstance but don't think there is a match for this.
In the example below, I want x to be doubled after an instance of SomeType is created, namely, I want the constructor taking the ref int version to be called.

Also, how does MS define the 'best match' algorithm for CreatInstance method?

```
internal sealed class SomeType
{

    //consturctor with non-reference parameter
    public SomeType(int x)
    {
        x *= 3;
    }

   //constructor with reference parameter 
    public SomeType(ref int x)
    {
        x *= 2;
    }
}

class Program 
{
     private static void main()
     {
        var param = new object[] {4}; // constructor parameter
        Console.WriteLine("Param Before consturctor called: " + param[0]);
        Object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SomeType), param);
        Console.WriteLine("Param after constuctor called: " + param[0]);
     }
}
```

Comment: "How does MS define..." It doesn't. `Activator.CreateInstance` is convenient, but almost literally means "make me an object and I don't care how". It's not exactly fast either... so if you know you want to invoke a particular constructor, it's usually better to do that directly.

Comment: @JeroenMostert it doesn't? I mean it has to find a constructor match when there is more than one potential match based on something. That's why MS said CreateInstance will try to find a match based on the 'best match'.

Comment: I meant "MS does not define exactly what 'best possible match' is supposed to mean".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to match the `ref int x` parameter, you can create an instance using `Type.GetConstructor` and passing it an `System.Int32&` as a parameter:

```
var ctor = typeof(SomeType).GetConstructor(new[] { Type.GetType("System.Int32&") });
var constructorParameters = new object[] { 1 };
SomeType someType = (SomeType)ctor.Invoke(constructorParameters);
```

**Edit:**

As @mikez suggested, it is even better to use `typeof(int).MakeByRefType()` instead of `System.Int32&`:

```
var ctor = typeof(SomeType).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int).MakeByRefType(); });
var constructorParameters = new object[] { 1 };
SomeType someType = (SomeType)ctor.Invoke(constructorParameters);
```

Comment: So it's no longer possible to use Activator.CreateInstance in such a situation?

Comment: I looked it up, i see no proper overload that takes in parameter types. So i'm assuming it isn't possible.

Comment: Note that `typeof(int).MakeByRefType()` is the way to create a `ref` type if you don't want to the type name in a string like `Type.GetType("System.Int32&")`.